# Distinguishing adjacent visited links

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

I've often seen people to [write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35497464/1468366) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638760/1468366) [adjacent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855171/1468366) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34851564/1468366), and I've [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36197064/1468366) [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27157147/1468366) [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18094309/1468366).

Today I noticed that at least for visited links on the main SO site, there appears to be nothing to visually distinguish multiple adjacent links from one big link. They are the same color, have no underline which could be broken up, and the formatting of visited links doesn't change when hovering, although unvisited links become a lighter shade of blue.

It would be nice if the design could help users notice that when they hover over (or click on) one of these links that they might have missed stuff referenced by the others.

Technically speaking, I see these rules in the SO `all.css` stylesheet:

```
a:hover { color: #3af; text-decoration: none }
.post-text a:visited { color: #005999 }
```

Of these two, the second is more specific, so the coloring of a visited link will take precedence over the coloring of a link being hovered above. Therefore a good solution would be creating a hover rule which is at least as specific as the visited rule.